# How to update apache-utils 2.2 to 2.4 on ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, server, apache2

I started playing with ubuntu server edition. I'm still extremely new to ubuntu, but I can't seem to figure this problem out. I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server. I need to use htpasswd to generate some password hashes, but bcrypt is supported only in apache2-utils 2.4.

The latest version of this package is 2.2.22 in ubuntu 12.04 repository. I don't want to install it by source since that is extremely messy and hard to remove it in the future.

Is there an official ppa by apache to get the latest version? Or is there a another relatively easy and secure way of updating to the latest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was going to leave this as a comment, but I don't have enough rep to post a comment. So I will write it as an answer. This might help your cause or might not or maybe you have already found another solution. In any case, here is my solution. Adding a ppa that carries the latest package you are looking for. You can find one that fits your need. Or you can add this one, ppa:ondrej/php5. I use this ppa to stay up to date with php, but he started adding latest apache as well. Hope it helps, you or anyone else that might be looking for an answer. Thank you.

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
```

Answer (score -1):

Repositories are not the only way to install.
You can also use Gdebi.
Get the .deb from 
http://packages.debian.org/sid/i386/apache2-utils/download
And use Gdebi to install it.
(You might have to uninstall 2.2 first).

Comment: You should not mix debian and ubuntu packages!